# I am working with PHP and have an Array of Arrays that looks something like this:

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, merge

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [gr_number] => 1
            [batch] => A
            [maths] => 80/100
            [english] => 80/100
            [science] => 80/100
            [hindi] => 80/100
            [computer] => 80/100
            [socialscience] => 85/100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [gr_number] => 2
            [batch] => A
            [maths] => 80/100
            [english] => 80/100
            [science] => 80/100
            [hindi] => 80/100
            [computer] => 80/100
            [socialscience] => 86/100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [gr_number] => 3
            [batch] => A
            [maths] => 80/100
            [english] => 80/100
            [science] => 80/100
            [hindi] => 80/100
            [computer] => 80/100
            [socialscience] => 87/100
        )

)
```

As you can see, their are some suject element  in the main array, o I would like to merge the all subject  elements in the same array ,like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [gr_number] => 1
            [batch] => A
            [result_details] => maths : 80/100,english:80/100,science:80/100,hindi:80/100,computer:80/100,socialscience:85/100;
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [gr_number] => 2
            [batch] => A
            [result_details] => maths : 80/100,english:80/100,science:80/100,hindi:80/100,computer:80/100,socialscience:85/100;  
      )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [gr_number] => 3
            [batch] => A
            [result_details] => maths : 80/100,english:80/100,science:80/100,hindi:80/100,computer:80/100,socialscience:85/100;  
        )

)
```

Comment: You have to use `array_reduce` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) in conjunction with `array_map` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: are subjects are static? the same 6 subjects in every array?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a new element `result_details` inside the `foreach` loop with combined values from other elements and unset the ones you don't need later:

```
foreach($arr as &$val){
    $val['result_details']='maths:'.$val['maths'].',english:'.$val['english'].',science:'.$val['science'].',hindi:'.$val['hindi'].',computer:'.$val['computer'].',socialscience:'.$val['socialscience'];
    unset($val['maths'],$val['english'],$val['science'],$val['science'],$val['hindi'],$val['computer'],$val['socialscience']);
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/5ElBHYji)**

Answer (score 0):

You may use `array_map` in conjunction with `array_diff_key` and `array_intersect_key`.
Somehow like this:

```
$keys = array('gr_number', 'batch');
$excludes = array_combine($keys, array_fill(0, count($keys), 0));
$result = array_map(
    function ($arr) use($excludes) {
        $ret = array_intersect_key($arr, $excludes);
        $arr = array_diff_key($arr, $excludes);
        $ret['result_details'] = implode(', ', array_map(
            function ($v1, $v2) { return "$v1:$v2"; },
            array_keys($arr), array_values($arr)
        ));
        return $ret;
    },
    $array
);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/ftUgAY)